# use vue3 and vue-cli to develop chrome extension, how to hot reload the code

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-extension, vuejs3

Use vue-cli to create a vue3 project to develop chrome extension, now it work. But the problem is the project need to rebuild when the code change every time. And it spent a lot of time.

So I try to watch code change:

```
vue-cli-service build --watch
```

Then there get error

> Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

the manifest_version

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    ...
}
```

Comment: do you have some sample extension with Vue for manifest v3? I've tried to migrate my project from Vue2 and manifest v2 and was unable to get it working.

Comment: yes I have. You can see it at https://github.com/Kobshobe/qy_translate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your manifest `content_security_policy` doesn't have `unsafe-eval`, e.g.:

```json
// This is for manifest v3
"content_security_policy": {
  "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';"
}
```

You can also add the devtool option to vue.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: (config) => {
    config.devtool = 'inline-source-map'
  },
};
```

Just make sure your choice of source map generation doesn't use eval - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/